# Javascript global variable getting set to a new value

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and coding in general, and I could use some help.

I am setting a global variable (generatedNumbers) equal to another variable (numbers) so that I can do some validation on the array. However, when I change the value of numbers, my global variable generatedNumbers gets changed as well. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var generatedNumbers;

function generateNumbers(numberOfNumbers) {
    'use strict';
    var i;
    generatedNumbers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i = i + 1) {
        generatedNumbers.push(generateRandomNumber(9).toString());
    }
}

function checkEachValidNumberUsed(userExpression, numbers) {
    'use strict';
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < userExpression.length; i = i + 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j = j + 1) {
            if (userExpression[i] === numbers[j]) {
                numbers.splice(j, 1);
                window.console.log(generatedNumbers);
            }
        }
    }
    if (numbers.length !== 0) {
        return true;
    }
}

function validateExpression(userExpression) {
    'use strict';
    var numbers, validUserInput;
    numbers = generatedNumbers;
    window.console.log(generatedNumbers);
        if (checkEachValidNumberUsed(userExpression, numbers)) {
            document.getElementById("feedbackText").innerHTML = "Each number must be used exactly once.";
    } else {
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You say "I am setting a global variable (generatedNumbers) equal to another variable (numbers)", but here, you're actually setting `numbers` to `generatedNumbers`: `numbers = generatedNumbers;`

Comment: Your code is missing a closing bracket } for the last else statement, is this a typo?

Comment: Where is declared generateRandomNumber() ?

Comment: in js for objects the value of the variable is a reference. so when you change your array in one place, it will change everywhere.
look here http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays (and all other non-primitive types) are pass-by-reference, not copied, when you use the assignment operator `=` or pass them to a function, so any changes made to `numbers` (or the values of the elements of `numbers`) will be reflected in `generatedNumbers`.

For your array here, `numbers = generatedNumbers.slice(0);` will sufficiently clone the array, but keep in mind that if the contents of the array is not a primitive type (e.g. any object that you use the `new` keyword to create) will not be cloned: both arrays will reference the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

That's because they both refer to the same object. If you want to make a copy of `generatedNumbers` (which I think you want to do in `validateExpression`) use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
numbers = generatedNumbers.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript if you have an array

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
```

and assign `a` to another variable

```
var b = a;
```

the two are referring the very same array object... for example after

```
b.push(99);
```

`a` will also see the mutated array.

If you want to make a copy you need to do so explicitly for example with

```
var b = a.slice();
```